# CSS Magento misalignment of div's

Tags: css, magento

I am setting up a Magento website and purchased a theme from Themeforest for Magento. 
I then added a background image to the theme instead of the default white colored page background.

Now what seems to be happening is the entire sides main div becomes pushed over the the right, but only when viewing in some browers such as Chrome and only when you are viewing the site on a large sized screen. To be more specific on my 18" PC monitor, using Chrome, FF, and IE the site looks fine, but when an associate goes to look at the site and he has a larger monitor, he says the site looks different in Chrome, FF etc.

Also, there is a mis-alignment as seen in the below screenshot from him:
http://bit.ly/QnlrVA

However, I can not reproduce this and can not even figure out the css issue.

The site if people can look and give feedback is at http://bit.ly/R1RV8S

The other issue is that when you view a specific category's product listing page, the products listing becomes right aligned. As a result, the normal right side column boxes (the compare products boxes etc) drop down to a new row instead being next to the product listing. This happens on both my computer monitors as well as everyone elses, and in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For the background - you just need a wider graphic. like > 1600px. Your current background image is just too small to cover wide screens. you could also set the `background-color` prop to "black" or whatever color you need (some kind of dark blue). Or set it to repeat.

As far as the right column issue goes - go into 
`catalog -> manage categories -> <your category> ->design ->custom design` and try one of the two column layouts (probably 2 column with right bar).

in your theme the 'col-wrapper' rule + the 'right-column' is greater than your overall width, so its bumping it down. One of the other layouts may fix this... or you can attempt to change the values for that column. (note that you make make unintended changes by doing this - so test your theme thoroughly).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a big screen to test it out on right now , but this should help:

```
body         
 {
    background:url(../images/stymulus_bg_pg.jpg); 
    font:12px/1.55 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666; 
    text-align:center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;      /*this */
    left:0px;                   /* and this */
    width:   **set to the width of the background image , it shouldn't strech***
  }
```

This will set your whole body absolutely positioned to the left , and it will also stop anything from comming outside of the body, unless something intentionally tries to go outside it's parent.